# Adding laser sensors to Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, laser, node, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

I have tried to add laser node to gazebo using the following code:

```
    <!-- BASE LASER ATTACHMENT -->
    <erratic_hokuyo_laser parent="base_link">
            <origin xyz="0.18 0 0.11" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </erratic_hokuyo_laser>
```

but I got the following error:

Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py /home/nouf/catkin_ws/src/chapter5_tutorials/urdf/robot1_base_03.xacro] returned with code [1].

Param xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I found out that the erratic_description package doesn't work with indigo version (which I'm currently using).
Is there another package or another way to add a laser node to Gazebo ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207006/adding-laser-sensors-to-gazebo/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

May be this [gazebo tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) will help I guess . There they mentions about adding lasers in URDf model.

```
<gazebo reference="your_link_name">
<plugin name="your_link_laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
... plugin parameters ...
</plugin>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) with karma: 233 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1